# SQL insert into Table issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a a user log for our access database; however, if the system crashes, it does not properly record the user logging out. So I'm trying to create a code to check to see if the user is listed as logged in prior to creating a record.

Here is my code:

```
Function LogOn()
   Dim sUser As String
   Dim sSQL As String

   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   sUser = Environ("username")
   sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLog ( UserID )" _
    & "SELECT '" & sUser & "' AS [User] & WHERE tblUserLog.UserID='" & sUser & "' AND tblUserLog.LogOn Is Null & From tblUserLog;"
   DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

I'm getting an error message of

> "must have at least one destination table".

I do not get the error message if I remove the WHERE statement.

Thanks for your help.
Sorin

Comment: select * from table. you dont have table name in your query.

Comment: Missing `FROM` clause

Comment: @Sorin . . . Print out `sSQL` and the answer will probably be obvious.  Isn't that an obvious next step anyway?  Easier than writing a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `From` clause missing

Comment: Your select query is a bit mixed..  You have a couple of "&"  in sql,  and the "where" before the "from".

Comment: He does have from clause at the end

Comment: sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLog ( UserID )" _
    & "SELECT '" & sUser & "' AS [User] From tblUserLog WHERE tblUserLog.UserID='" & sUser & "' AND tblUserLog.LogOn Is Null " try this.

Comment: `& from` ?? what's that ?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I apologize if this was a dumb question. New to SQL coding. The new code works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FROM` clause is placed at wrong position. Try Updated Query

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLog ( UserID )" _
& "SELECT '" & sUser & "' AS [User] From tblUserLog WHERE tblUserLog.UserID='" & sUser & "' AND tblUserLog.LogOn Is Null ;"
                     -----------------^
```